# Angular project not displaying on IE (10,11 and Edge)

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11, ecmascript-5

I am working on an angular project. The web page is well displayed on Chrome and Mozilla but when it comes to IE 11, nothing, the page is locked on the loading page.
IE11.0.9600.19100
[Error message on IE 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCUmz.png) I can't even track it down [debug error empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugUMW.png)
I have the following configuration:

> package.json:

```
"webpack": "^3.12.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1",
```

> tsconfig.json:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./node_modules",
    "paths": {
      "ng-boosted": ["./src/index"]
    }
  }
```

> polyfills.ts

```
    // Polyfills

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. */
import 'core-js/es5/';

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

import 'core-js/client/shim';

import 'reflect-metadata';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

/** Evergreen browsers require these. */
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

// Typescript emit helpers polyfill
import 'ts-helpers';

require('zone.js/dist/zone');

if ('production' === process.env.ENV) {
  // Production

} else {
  // Development

  Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

  require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');

}
```

I followed those recommandation [Angular configuration](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#core-es6)
Everything I saw on the internet didn't help.

Here is the error output the console is displaying on IE.

```
>     eval("/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__ = __webpack_require__(499);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_ssr_window__ = __webpack_require__(288);\n/**\n * Swiper 4.3.5\n * Most modern mobile touch slider and framework with hardware accelerated transitions\n *
> http://www.idangero.us/swiper/\n *\n * Copyright 2014-2018 Vladimir
> Kharlampidi\n *\n * Released under the MIT License\n *\n * Released
> on: July 31, 2018\n */\n\n\n\n\nconst Methods = {\n  addClass:
> __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"a\" /* addClass */],\n  removeClass: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"b\" /* removeClass */],\n  hasClass:
> __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"c\" /* hasClass */],\n  toggleClass: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"d\" /* toggleClass */],\n  attr:
> __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"e\" /* attr */],\n  removeAttr: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"f\" /* removeAttr */],\n  data:
> __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"g\" /* data */],\n  transform: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"h\" /* transform */],\n  transition:
> __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"i\" /* transition */],\n  on:
> __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"j\" /* on */],\n  off: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"k\" /* off */],\n  trigger: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"l\" /* trigger */],\n  transitionEnd: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"m\" /* transitionEnd */],\n  outerWidth:
> __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"n\" /* outerWidth */],\n  outerHeight:
> __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"o\" /* outerHeight */],\n  offset:
> __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"p\" /* offset */],\n  css: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"q\" /* css */],\n  each: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"r\" /* each */],\n  html: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"s\" /* html */],\n  text: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"t\" /* text */],\n  is: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"u\" /* is */],\n  index:
> __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"v\" /* index */],\n  eq: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"w\" /* eq */],\n  append:
> __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_dom7_dist_dom7_modular__[\"x\" /* append */],\n  prepend:
```

Comment: import 'classlist.js'; this import is missing from your polyfills. Run `npm install --save classlist.js` and add that import in polyfills

Comment: I added it but it doesn't change a thing :/.

Comment: In your tsconfig why don't you try for `"module": "es2015",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just update the version of Webpack by finding the right one, that is in compliance with my configuration.

> ```
> "webpack": "3.0.0",
> "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
> "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1",
> "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
> "webpack-merge": "^0.17.0"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Add below line in your index.html file in `<head>` section:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

and also uncomment all the line from your `src/polyfill.ts`

Comment: I have it already and i uncommented every line and it changed nothing. i am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Have tried to commenting first line in polyfill.ts? // import 'core-js/es5/'; because es6 cover allmost all the things of es5.

Answer (score 0):

There are some polyfills required for the angular app to be able to run in IE. Please check this post.

https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-and-internet-explorer-5e59bb6fb4e9